# Como puedo redefinir el método post de UpdateView y obtener su Pk de manera manual?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Tenía un código así y no funcionó. Mi idea es usar el PK de manera manual, ya que debo hacer una suma de datos para posteriormente actualizarlo

````
model = PedidosCliente
form_class = PedidoClienteForm
template_name = 'modals/pedido_cliente/editar_pedido_cliente.html'

def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
    pedido = PedidosCliente.objects.get(id_pedido = pk)
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance = pedido)
    if form.is_valid():
        enviar_datos_pedidos(form)
        return redirect('libreria:pedidos_cliente')
    else: 
        return render(request, 'pedidos.html', {'form':form}) ```
````

Comment: Quieres obtener el `pk` de la instancia o de la URL?